# Can't Click or Use Keyboard in my User Account

Tags: unity

All of a sudden, when I log in to my user account and Unity desktop shows up, I cannot click anything (but the mouse pointer moves), and the keyboard does not control anything. My desktop is totally locked up. I have to use main power to log out and reboot.

If I log in to the Guest desktop account, everything works fine. I can also log in to my account via SSH.

I am using 11.10. I have rebooted my system numerous times, and I have waited 30 minutes after log in just in case something is still loading.

What could the problem be? How can I resolve this problem without entirely losing files and settings?

Comment: Take a look at your `/var/log/syslog` file for suspicious log messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround.

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

On the command line type:

```
ps -elf | grep nautilus
```

You get two rows, ignore the row with grep,

From the other row, note the fourth column, it is the *pid* of nautilus.

Kill nautilus with:

```
sudo kill -9 pid
```

Where pid is the number just noted.

Your graphic login should display. Log in and have fun until it freezes again.

Comment: Thanks. This was similar to the solution I eventually found, so choosing as best. The workaround I used was to killall compiz and then hit ALT CTRL F7 to start the GUI again. The permanent solution (at least so far) was to remove the Nvidia driver, and reinstall the recommended one rather than the "post-upgrade" one.